# Extract a specific column from a list of list data

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of list where I want to extract a specific column from each data set.I used the following code to get the 7th column of each data in the list of list.

```
lapply(out, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) y[,7]))
```

However, it looks like some data has less than 7 columns. But I need to get only the 7th column wherever available and combine all of them into one data frame (The column name may be different in each data in list of list but I am sure that the required information is available only in the 7th column)

Comment: please share some reproducible data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep dataframe that has more than 6 columns using `Filter`. To get data in one dataframe use `do.call` + `rbind`

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(out, function(x) 
             do.call(rbind, lapply(Filter(function(z) ncol(z) > 6, x),
                             function(y) y[,7]))))
```

---

Using `purrr` might be shorter :

```
library(purrr)
map_df(out, function(x) map_df(keep(x, ~ncol(.x) > 6), function(y) y[,7]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Can we also include from which file the data is coming as well in the final dataframe

Comment: map_df(out, function(x) map_df(keep(x, ~ncol(.x) > 6), function(y) y[,7], .id="source")) - I have just added the .id to get the file name. But the problem is , i get the sheet names of the excel file but the the actual excel file name.

Comment: I don't have your data to test this but you can also `".id"` in outer `map_df`. Try `map_df(out, function(x) map_df(keep(x, ~ncol(.x) > 6), function(y) y[,7], .id="source1"), .id = "source2")`

Comment: That's perfect!!